# Can I define alias in Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-console

I tried to edit my ~/.irbrc file
and define show_tbls method to fetch the tables I have,
because the command is to long , so I tried to make a function for easier use.

```
require 'hirb' ; Hirb.enable
require 'irb/completion'

def show_tbls
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
end
```

When I ran the show_tbls
it showed the error as followings

```
1.9.3-p448 :001 > show_tbls()
NoMethodError: undefined method `show_tbls' for main:Object
        from (irb):1
        from /home/poc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
        from /home/poc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
        from /home/poc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
1.9.3-p448 :002 > show_tbls
NameError: undefined local variable or method `show_tbls' for main:Object
```

Answer (score 5):

define your methods inside Kernel Module

```
module Kernel
  def show_tbls
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables
  end
end
```

Comment: excuse me , what file should I modify ?

Comment: @SaidKaldybaev -- what are the potential implications of modifying `.irbrc`? Are there any?